# Close upcoming Debug Assertion

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit, assertion

I am testing Debug DLLs with NUnit and it is very annoying that with every testrun a large amount of Debug Assertions come up.

So i have written a tool which is polling for a new Debug Assertion. the tool is iterating to all windows every x milliseconds and checks if the title is one of the collection of possible Debug Assertion window titles.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
void main()
{
    var thread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
    thread.Start();
}

private void ThreadMethod()
{
    while(true)
    {
        foreach(var title in possibleWindowTitles)
        {
            IntPtr windowHandle = FindWindowHandle(title);

            if(windowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetToForeground(windowHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("%I);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The codeline `SendKeys.SendWait("%I")` sends the keycombination of `ALT + I` to the window, which is the keycombination for the "Continue" Button.

**My Question is:** 
Is there a better option? something like:

- An event when a new window comes up
- A better method of closing the window (the `CloseWindow` method from the `User32.dll` hasn't worked for me -- no Exception, but nothing happens)
- A better solution for the `SetToForeGround()` workaround
- The best way would be an suppression of the Assertion -- Is that possible?

My way works, but i think my solution is very prone to errors. So i hole there is someone with a good idea

Comment: I'll post as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the behavior of the dialog box. This is a behavior provided by the DefaultTraceListener, which is configurable in code or via config file. The documentation for [Debug.Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z(v=vs.110).aspx) mentions this.

In the config file, you can turn off the UI like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <assert assertuienabled="false" logfilename="c:\myFile.log" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can also just remove the default trace listener from the collection via the config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="myListener"  type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"    initializeData="c:\myListener.log" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Either of these can also be done via code, with the `Debug.Listeners` collection.

Comment: Thx for your answer. At the moment i have not that much time. i will report back when i checked it ;)